# Is it possible to login from my application into dropbox without having the user being redirected to a internet browser?

Tags: c++, cloud, dropbox

I want to create an application where i will be providing a dialog box to enter username and password for their dropbox account, And when they click on "Ok" button the user account should be connect and when they are logged into their account, my application will provide them with UI which will allow them to sync the application data to dropbox. Later i want to do the same with Google Drive. Note: I am using C++ and Making MFC application, So please give answers considering the programming language.

**My question: Is it possible to login from my application into dropbox without having the user being redirected to a internet browser ?**

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way for a Dropbox user to authorize an app is via OAuth (which requires them visiting `dropbox.com` in a browser).